# MD5Algorithm-Add 2 md5 values

Tags: java, algorithm, hash

Is there a algorithm to add 2 md5 values

We process data in parts. Currently I have the algorithm from Jon Howell . Here is what I do now

1. Calculate the message digest of the 1st part which is

> ```
> private int buf[];    // These were originally unsigned ints.
>           // This Java code makes an effort to avoid sign traps.
>           // buf[] is where the hash accumulates.     
> long bits;    // This is the count of bits hashed so far.     
> byte in[];    // This is a buffer where we  stash bytes until we have
>           // enough (64) to perform a transform operation.
> ```

2. I can store the combination of these 3 values in my DB and then recreate this object again and process the 2nd part

This creates a sequential order of processing content which we dont want. I want to process all the parts in parallel, which means I need to be able to calculate the md5 value adding 2 of the message digest algorithms. Do anyone have tried such an algorithm

Comment: Can you clarify what you hope to accomplish with this? I can't tell exactly what you're asking, but a MD5 of two MD5 inputs is possible (and would be a unique new hash value).

Comment: The md5 calculated from the 2 md5 inputs should be equal to the md5 of the sum of the contents as well

Comment: It will not be. Cryptographically secure hashes do not work that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. You can't produce the hash of the concatenation of A and B from B and the hash of A.

This is by design. Hashing algorithms in the crypto works are designed to work sequentially.

If you wanted to add B onto what you'd already calculated from A, you'd need the entire state of the hash function after hashing A, which will be more than just its output at that point.

What you can do, though, is calculate H(H(A).H(B)). This is certainly not the same, but it will give you a cryptographically secure fingerprint of A and B.